# Parsing a file into separate strings

Tags: c#, file, parsing

File consist of 2 line of text.
need to parse the file so that each line of text is assigned to a string. my string variables are "PhoneNumber" and "Location" and the incoming file is stored in string "line".

```
 using (var sr = new StreamReader(incoming))
                {
                    
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        PhoneNumber = ??
                        Location = ??
                        
                    }
                }
```

Comment: We can't help you without more information. In particular, what's in the file. If the first line is the phone number and the second the location, then initialize a counter (`var lineNumer=0;`) outside the loop, increment it inside the loop (as the last statement within the loop's code, `++loopNumber;`), and use that to decide to which variable you should assign `line`.

Comment: the file is a txt file and consist of 2 lines of text. Line is a phone number and line 2 is a location (Nebraska) and need to take each line from txt file and parse into PhoneNumber to consist of line 1 and Location to consist of line 2.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
using System.IO;

string Phonenumber = "";
string Location = "";
string[] filecontent = File.ReadAllLines("Filepath");
if (filecontent.Length > 0)
    Phonenumber = filecontent[0];
if (filecontent.Length > 1)
    Location = filecontent[1];
```

**Edit:**

Option 2 using StreamReader:

```
string Phonenumber = "";
string Location = "";
int LineCount = 0;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"Path"))
{
    var linecontent = "";
    while ((linecontent = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    if (LineCount == 0)
        Phonenumber = linecontent;
    if (LineCount == 1)
        Location = linecontent;
    LineCount++;
    }
}
```

Option 3 also using StreamReader:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"Path"))
{
    string Phonenumber = "";
    string Location = "";
    string[] filecontent = sr.ReadToEnd().Split("\n"); //Read text from file and split it into single lines
    if (filecontent.Length > 0)
        Phonenumber = filecontent[0];
    if (filecontent.Length > 1)
        Location = filecontent[1];
}
```

Comment: Not having much luck.

Comment: Does it matter that I am using "using (var sr = new StreamReader(incoming))" to retrieve file?

Comment: It only matters, when you call the read text function, make sure you read the text as individual line to an array. Or if you read it as one text split it using string.split("\n"); and enter that array to the filecontent array.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check if it works another way

Comment: that all worked, thanks for the help.